# How to add customized component in C#?

Tags: c#, autocad

I need to call acadcolor component from visual studio.when i add the component it's fine.

After I need to use that component so just I drag and drop that control to windows form visual studio automatically closed without passed any message.

Can anybody  know how to add and how to work with acadcolor component from visual studio?

Thanks advance.

Comment: Is this the solution you need: [AcCtrl.dll in VS 2008 64bit](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/NET/AcCtrl-dll-in-VS-2008-64bit/td-p/3115750)? Try adding the control programatically, as shown in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ADN article on just what Alex Filipovici was mentioning:
[Use 64-bit ActiveX Component from a .NET Assembly](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/07/use-64-bit-activex-component-from-a-net-assembly.html)

There are other alternatives too.  Here's an ADN article replicating the control with WPF: [WPF Implementation To Mimic Color Layer Controls](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/07/wpf-implementation-to-mimic-color-layer-controls.html).

You can also open the color dialog if it's to select a color.  That's what I've done most recently:

```
using acColor = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Colors;
using acWindows = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Windows;
//...
    public acColor.Color GetAutoCADColor()
    {
        acWindows.ColorDialog colorDialog = new acWindows.ColorDialog();

        DialogResult dialogResult = new DialogResult();
        dialogResult = colorDialog.ShowDialog();
        switch (dialogResult)
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                return colorDialog.Color;
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                return Color.Empty.ConvertToAutoCADColor();
            default:
                return Color.Empty.ConvertToAutoCADColor();
        }
    }
```

Extension methods:

```
internal static class ColorExtensions
{
    internal static Color ConvertToWindowsColor(this acColor.Color acColor)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(acColor.ColorValue.ToArgb());
    }

    internal static acColor.Color ConvertToAutoCADColor(this Color winColor)
    {
        return acColor.Color.FromRgb(winColor.R, winColor.G, winColor.B);
    }
}
```

Just a thought or two.